# Using Fetch with React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to use fetch to retrieve my data, and then `setState` to apply it in the `componentDidMount`.  I'm getting the log that says the component mounted, anything after the `fetch`, included the simple console logs are not working.  Is there something simple wrong with my syntax?  I have verified that the API does work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';


let policyContent = '';

class TinyEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            
    this.state = { content: '' };

        this.handleEditorChange = this.handleEditorChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(`Component did mount`);
        fetch("/policy")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(`You got your results... now what?`);
                policyContent = result;
                console.log(policyContent[0]);
                this.setState({policyContent});
            });
    }

    handleEditorChange(content, editor) {
        this.setState({ content });
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(`Button was clicked.`);
        console.log(this.state.content);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <Editor
                        apiKey='yf9eajz93s3akrlb24b8ja9xcszddbxx22x4ug8c2q5boxw3'
                        className="mceEditor"
                        id='myTextArea'
                        init={{
                            height: 500,
                            editor_selector: 'mceEditor',
                            menubar: false,
                            browser_spellcheck: true,
                            contextmenu: true,
                            branding: false,
                            plugins: [
                                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                                'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                                'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
                            ],
                            toolbar:
                                'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | help'
                        }}
                        onEditorChange={this.handleEditorChange}
                        value={this.state.content}
                    />
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TinyEditor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run your code using a online api. every thing is working fine. Please replace the code of `componentDidMount` and check the output for testing.

```
componentDidMount() {
        console.log(`Component did mount`);
        fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(`You got your results... now what?`);
                policyContent = result.results[0];
                console.log(policyContent);
                this.setState({content: policyContent.category});
            });
    }
```

**Please check the output screen where the text of Editor is coming from api.**

[image]

Comment: Actually, yes, when I cut and past your code, it works perfectly.  So there must be an issue in what is returning from my api.  Thank you!